# Invalid operands to binary expression ('std::ostream' (aka 'basic_ostream<char>' and 'void')

Tags: c++, функции, потоки-данных, вывод

Пытаюсь написать функцию для решения квадратного уравнения, и получаю вот такую ошибку в 26 строке:

```
Invalid operands to binary expression ('std::ostream' (aka 'basic_ostream<char>' and 'void')
```

Но я не совсем понимаю, почему ругается компилятор и что он от меня хочет. Подключила библиотеку `<ostream>`, но это не сработало. Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться! Спасибо.

Вот код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <ostream>

using namespace std;

void Kva(float a,float b, float c)
{
    float Diskr, x1, x2;

    Diskr = (b*b) - (4*a*c);

    if (Diskr >= 0)
    {x1 = ((-b) - sqrt(Diskr))/(2*a);
    x2 = ((-b) + sqrt(Diskr))/(2*a);
    cout << "x1 =" << " " << x1 << ";" << " " << "x2 =" << " " << x2 << endl;}
    else {cout << "Diskriminant < 0" << endl;}

    //return x1;
}

int main()
{
    float a, b, c;
    cin >> a >> b >> c;
    cout << Kva(a, b, c) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Что вы хотели вывести в этой строке `cout << Kva(a, b, c) << endl;` ?  Kva - ничего не возвращает.

Comment: зачем здесь метка Qt?

Comment: @BeardedBeaver писала в Qt, поэтому поставила. Извините, если отвлекло

Comment: @Chorkov хотела вывести результат, то есть x1 и x2. Спасибо, я теперь поняла в чём ошибка

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваше `Kva` само выводит все, что нужно (надеюсь :))
Поэтому вам достаточно написать

```
cin >> a >> b >> c;
Kva(a, b, c);
```

Ошибка возникает из-за того, что функция объявлена как `void`, т.е. не возвращающая никакого значения. А выводить ничего - это не совсем то же, что ничего не выводить :), вот компилятор и поясняет, что он не знает, как вывести "ничего"...

Comment: Спасибо огромное за объяснение! Теперь хоть понятно стало, очень помогли. Я только начинающая, поэтому правда, спасибо!